# Angular SharePoint 2016 custom list display data

Tags: angular, sharepoint

I am trying to display SharePoint 2016 (On Prim) custom list item data into a webpart page with help of CEWP.
1) I created a custom list names "AngularDisplay" with default column "Title"
2) checked the JSON data rendering by url "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('AngularDisplay')/items?$select=Title"
3) Copied the below code at CEWP

```
{
<html>
<title>Display Operation ByAJS</title> 
<head>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script> 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('DisplayCtrl',function($scope,$http) {
$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('AngularDisplay')/items?$select=Title",
        headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }
      }).then(function onSuccess(response) {
         var data = response.data;
         $scope.DisplayListData = data.d.results;
         }).catch(function onError(response) {
            alert("Error occured during data fetch");
           }); 
});
</script> 
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="DisplayCtrl"> 
   <table> 
      <tbody>
         <tr> 
            <th>ID</th> 
          </tr> 
         <tr ng-repeat="customer in DisplayListData"> 
            <td>{{customer.Title}}</td> 
          </tr> 
      </tbody>
   </table> 
</div> 
</body>
</html>

}
```

Am I missing some thing here. Please suggest.

Fire bug is just providing 2 warnings:

[Deprecation] 'window.webkitStorageInfo' is deprecated. Please use 'navigator.webkitTemporaryStorage' or 'navigator.webkitPersistentStorage' instead.
AsyncDeltaManager$_retrieveDelta @ start.js?rev=TAG0:1

[Deprecation] Application Cache is deprecated in non-secure contexts, and will be restricted to secure contexts in M69, around September 2018. Please consider migrating your application to HTTPS, and eventually shifting over to Service Workers.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doWjl.jpg)

Please ping me at creativemonktimepass@gmail.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that you are using ng-app tag inside body tag which is getting omitted. so you need to include ng-app tag inside parent div as below:

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="DisplayCtrl">

Code with output:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Pradip, But no luck still issue persist.

Comment: You can check this updated solution that I have posted

Comment: <body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="DisplayCtrl"> 
   <table> 
      <tbody>
         <tr> 
            <th>ID</th> 
          </tr> 
         <tr ng-repeat="customer in DisplayListData"> 
            <td>{{customer.Title}}</td> 
          </tr> 
      </tbody>
   </table> 
</div> 
</body>
</html>

Comment: It seems I am doing some small blunder Can you please have a look at snapshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/doWjl.jpg and ping me at creativemonktimepass@gmail.com

Comment: Code in your screenshot looks fine, add a debugger inside controller and check

Comment: Thanks for your support @Pradip . I do not know why but the moment I disabled Minimal Download Strategy from my site feature, The data got rendered automatically.